# example command with configurable sleep duration with configurable output

Tags: shell, scripting

i need to write a simple shell script or run command with configurable sleep duration with configurable output. Could someone point me an example which satisfies this requirement. thanks

Comment: You will get a much friendlier reception on SO if (a) your question includes all needed specific, and (b) you show the code you have tried so far, and (c) the errors or problems that you found with that code.

Comment: here is what I tried, but I don't know what is configurable sleep and configurable output. Hence I raised my question here. #!/bin/bash
/sbin/ifconfig | awk '/inet addr/{print substr($2,6)}'
sleep 2
hostname
exit